# How to write a function with loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started learning python, so very new and I am stuck on a question for which I am doing an assignment. I would appreciate some help in this.
Problem as follow:

I have to code a function called 'halve_to_2' that only accepts 1 numeric output.
If the number <= 0, RETURN -1
If the number > 0, divide that integer over-and-over by 2 until it becomes smaller than 2.
You have to RETURN that smaller-than-2 number

Now I did have a go at this, but did something wrong as it returned (-1) into infinity and my pc ran out of memory.

My attempt looks like below and is partial(I know as I did not yet even incorporate the second part where one would keep dividing), but hoping to get someone to provide the correct output if possible.

My attempt:

```
def halve_to_2( num ):
    while num /2 <= 0:
           return(num)

    while true:
        return(-1)
k=5
print (halve_to_2(k))
```

Thank you,

Surien

Comment: Try to understand the usage of `while`. While will execute a (set of) command(s) until some condition is not met. Try thinking what is that condition, and when you want to stop. Notice that before the execution of the loop, you might have a unique check that will exit the function early in your case

Comment: in question you say `"if the number <= 0..., if the number >0 ..."` - it shows that you need rather two `if`, not `while`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while num/2 <= 0:
    return (num/2)
```

will just return the value of `num/2` in the first iteration. You need to return that value only when `num/2` becomes less than `2`:

```
def halve_to_2(num):
    while True:
        num = num / 2.0
        if num < 2:
            return num
```

It seems you can figure the other case out by yourself, when `num` is negative.